# How can I assign a URL to my IP (server, 18.04)?

Tags: server, 18.04, python, https

I recently got Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I just got a basic HTTP server running through Python http.server, socket, and socketserver modules.

Now I'm wondering how I can assign a URL to that IP and set up a public website.

It would be helpful if there was any way I could do it in python (due to my understanding python better than HTTP). But if I can't, just let me know.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte im trying to start a public website, Ubuntu Server is just the backend, sorry for unclarity

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This process is well documented and pretty much the same for all Linux distros. This is not about scripting, it is about hardware and software configuration.

There are numerous steps to create a public website, but the basic gist is:

- set up web server
- set up router to direct port 80 traffic to your server
- set up a domain name to point to the IP

You can follow any of these howtos:

- [Host a Website on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website-ubuntu-18-04/)
- [How to Set Up a Dedicated Web Server for Free](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free--net-2043)
- [How To Setup A Web Server And Host Website On Your Own Linux Computer﻿](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-setup-a-web-server-and-host-website-on-your-own-linux-computer)